# LINQ - building AND vs OR logic for multiple result sets

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find the most elegant way of finding exact matches across multiple `IEnumerable<T>` collections, using AND logic, rather than OR logic.

**Example**

```
public class IceCream
{
    public string Flavor { get; set; } // "Vanilla", "Choc Chip", "Mint"
    public bool ContainsNuts { get; set; }
    public ServingType { get; set; } // "Cup", "Cone", "Waffle Cone"
    public SprinklesType { get; set; } // "Choc", "HundredsAndThousands", "EdibleBallBearings"
}
```

My first step is that I want to be able to get all available ice creams by individual search terms:

```
IEnumerable<IceCream> IceCreamsByFlavor { get; set; }
IEnumerable<IceCream> IceCreamsByContainsNuts { get; set; }
IEnumerable<IceCream> IceCreamsByServingType { get; set; }
IEnumerable<IceCream> IceCreamsBySprinklesType { get; set; }
```

Now, I can OR these together to get a collection of ice creams that have ANY of the properties of the term:

```
return Enumerable.Empty<IceCream>()
    .Concat(IceCreamsByFlavor)
    .Concat(IceCreamsByContainsNuts)
    .Concat(IceCreamsByServingType)
    .Concat(IceCreamsBySprinklesType)
    .Distinct();
```

But now, say if my search term was:

```
Search(
    flavor: "Vanilla",
    containsNuts: true,
    servingType: ServingType.WaffleCone,
    sprinklesType: SprinkesType.HundredsAndThousands);
```

How do I get an `IEnumerable<IceCream>` that contains only ice creams that contain **ALL** of the terms, rather than *ANY* of them?

Comment: Something like `myIceCreams.Where(i => i.Flavors.Contains(f) && i.Nuts.Contains(n) && ...`. ? I'm not 100% clear on what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Concat`:

```
return IceCreamsByFlavor
    .Intersect(IceCreamsByContainsNuts)
    .Intersect(IceCreamsByServingType)
    .Intersect(IceCreamsBySprinklesType);
```

It will return only items that are in all collections.

Keep in mind that depending on how your equality comparison is implemented you might need to use to use [overload of `Intersect` with `IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx)